# Switching from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.10 my wifi router

Tags: wireless, networking, windows-7

I am switching from windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.10 and I burned Ubuntu on DVD and inserted and chose option 2 to install Ubuntu only and delete Win7 and anything else.

My problem is that I have wifi router that gives me internet and I set it up on windows 7 with a password.  My question is when I install Ubuntu 13.10 and remove Win7  will there be a problem with this router?  What should I do to set it up on Ubuntu?  Will the old password work with Ubuntu?

Comment: To be extra sure first boot into the liveCD by clicking on "Try Ubuntu" and see if you can use your wifi connection.

Comment: While the answer are correct, that does not mean you may not have trouble installing a driver or getting the driver to work especially if you do not have an ethernet connection. In most cases the wifi will or can be made to work but it may take a little effort. Try the liveCD is the best option, but not all drivers are preloaded on the liveCD either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no problem with the router in relation to installing Ubuntu or removing Windows 7. **Yes.** the old password will work with Ubuntu. No operating system will change the security information in your router. Regardless of OS it can be helpful to know your routers security details.

Using WEP or WPA, TKIP or EAP, etc. There's lots of good information to be found simply by googling router security settings. You may find this wiki [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_security) interesting.

If you have forgotten how you set it up, you can obtain all the relevant information by logging into your router.

If you have forgotten the password you used to lock down your router you can always reset to factory defaults (google reset *your router make and model*) and start over.

**Note that if you are forced to start over, all wireless clients on your network will have to be re-configured.**

Comment: thanks i had burned ubuntu 13.04 on dvd and creat a bootable usb and in the installation it recognized my wirless with the same password and work well but i am now facing another problem my dell inspiron 15r in ubuntu installation no installation types appear and no root file defined :(

Comment: I'm glad you got that sorted out. If any of the answers here were helpful, please upvote/accept. That's our way of saying thanks here and it helps other users with similar problems find the answers they need. If you have another question, please use the search box at the upper left and if you don't find solutions there, ask a separate question. We will do our best to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. It should work since the password is put on access to WiFi.
Ubuntu should automatically find your WiFi. Info should be in the top right corner.
All you need to do is to choose your WiFi and type in your password.

Comment: thanks i had burned ubuntu 13.04 on dvd and creat a bootable usb and in the installation it recognized my wirless with the same password and work well but i am now facing another problem my dell inspiron 15r in ubuntu installation no installation types appear and no root file defined :(